# capture the click of the Twitter "Tweet" button using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter, onclick

I have the following code on my site, which when it accesses Twitter's API generates it's own markup.

I'm looking to call a JavaScript function on the `onClick` even of this but, but as the markup changes it seems it's not as simple as just adding an `onClick` to the anchor.

How can I capture the click of the 'Tweet' button?

```
<div class="social_button twitter_button">
  <a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-count="horizontal">
    Tweet
  </a>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"></script>
</div>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14421429/attach-a-click-event-to-the-twitter-follow-button

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't handle click events on this element, because it's in an iFrame, however twitter gives you the opportunity to bind events to the button.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/ZwHBf/2/
Docs: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/intents/events

Code:
HTML:

```
<div class="social_button twitter_button">
    <div id="foo">
        <a href="https://google.com" class="twitter-share-button" data-count="horizontal">
    Tweet
  </a>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        window.twttr = (function (d, s, id) {
            var t, js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
            if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
            js = d.createElement(s);
            js.id = id;
            js.src = "//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";
            fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
            return window.twttr || (t = {
                _e: [],
                ready: function (f) {
                    t._e.push(f)
                }
            });
        }(document, "script", "twitter-wjs"));
    </script>
</div>​
```

JS:

```
twttr.events.bind('click', function(event) {
    console.log('clicked');
});​
```

Comment: For some reason, with this code I am getting an illegal character error on the console.log line at the end? `<script type="text/javascript"> twttr.events.bind('click', function(event) {
console.log('clicked');
});​ </script>`

Comment: Ignore me, apologies. I think there was a bad character copied over from the example. I re-typed your example and it worked. Excellent answer, kudos!

Comment: quick question on this. This fires when the button is clicked, is there any way to check if the tweet sent?

Comment: @David please read the link pointing to the Twitter docs. Your question might be answered there ;) hint: "tweet"

Comment: @Robin duh.. late night last night

Answer (score 0):

Adding a customized Twitter button to your website is a lot easier than you might think.

```
<a href="http://twitter.com/share">Tweet</a>
```

Yes, really, that's all it takes. Give your link some design love and tada! Your very own custom Twitter button.

**Opening the Twitter Share Box in a popup window**

To show the Twitter Share Box as a popup, simply add some lines of javascript to open the link in a new window. Here's an example using jQuery:

```
<a class="twitter popup" href="http://twitter.com/share">Tweet</a>

<script>
  $('.popup').click(function(event) {
    var width  = 575,
        height = 400,
        left   = ($(window).width()  - width)  / 2,
        top    = ($(window).height() - height) / 2,
        url    = this.href,
        opts   = 'status=1' +
                 ',width='  + width  +
                 ',height=' + height +
                 ',top='    + top    +
                 ',left='   + left;

    window.open(url, 'twitter', opts);

    return false;
  });
</script>
```

**Note:** This is just an example. You'll probably want to put the javascript code in a .js file and call it on document ready.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.popup').click(function(event) {
    // and so on...
  }
});
```

Setting a default message for the tweet

You can set a default text for the tweet adding a text parameter to the link:

```
<a class="twitter popup" href="http://twitter.com/share?text=This%20is%20so%20easy">Tweet</a>
```

Now when your users click on your Tweet link, the message "This is so easy" will appear in the tweet box by default.
[more..](http://www.webpop.com/blog/2011/02/16/add-a-custom-twitter-button-to-your-website)