# Attach a click() event to the twitter follow button?

Tags: javascript, twitter

I'd like to add a alert message on the page when a user clicks 'follow' button.
 how can i achieve this ?

here is code :

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/prajapat2010" class="twitter-follow-button"
data-show-count="false" data-dnt="true">Follow @prajapat2010</a>
<script>
    ! function (d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (!d.getElementById(id)) {
            js = d.createElement(s);
            js.id = id;
            js.src = "//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";
            fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
        }
    }(document, "script", "twitter-wjs");
</script>
```

Comment: Go to edit your question and click the question mark. Stackoverflow will nicely format your code for you, but it has to be entered in the appropriate format. Then it would be easy for others to see what is happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Twitter event callback to achieve this.

```
//Here is you normal twitter button code

//My custom function
function mycustom() {
  alert('this is a test')
}

//Bind the custom function with twitter event
twttr.ready(function (twttr) {
  twttr.events.bind('click', mycustom);
});
```

For more events, read the official doc: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/intents/events

Comment: @BillyChan The function "mycustom()" is not triggering most of the times.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ready' of undefined at <anonymous>:6:7