# Saving the data- attribute in to hidden field when tweet button is clicked

Tags: jquery, asp.net, .net, vb.net, twitter

I have my data displayed in a repeater control and I am trying to save a value in to the asp hidden field when each twitter tweet button is clicked. I am wiring up the click event for the tweet button. There is a data- attribute which stores an id value and I am using the click event to store the value in to the hidden field.

```
 $(".twitter-share-button").click(function(){
     $("#<%=hidTwitterSharedMonitorId.ClientID%>").val($(this).data('monitor').monitorId);                    
  });

<a href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet" class="twitter-share-button" data-monitor='{"monitorId":<%#Eval("ID")%>}' data-count="none">Tweet</a>
```

It doesnt seem like the id is not getting assigned to the hiddenfield. Could anyone have a look to review the code a bit to see what I am doing wrong.

Thanks,

Comment: possible duplicate of [capture the click of the Twitter "Tweet" button using jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11757170/capture-the-click-of-the-twitter-tweet-button-using-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

First, try to re-declare your anonymoous method, so it could receive a parameter:

```js
$('.twitter-share-button').click(function (e) { ...
```

---

Second, I believe your `$(this)` will refer to the instance of a share button (which you should observe in the browser's developer tool). And i would recommend to reference the element through the `id` attribute.

```js
..."ClientID%>").val($('#id-of-your-element').data('monitor')...
```

(About second I might be wrong in case you **are** intending to do that).

---

And third, jquery event handlers should be located **after** the elements they refer to, thus:

- Either switch the lines:

```js
<a href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet" class="twitter-share-button" data-monitor='{"monitorId":<%#Eval("ID")%>}' data-count="none">Tweet</a>

$(".twitter-share-button").click(function() {
    $("#<%=hidTwitterSharedMonitorId.ClientID%>").val($(this).data('monitor').monitorId);
});
```

- Or place the event handler to the document.load event:

```js
$(function () {
    $(".twitter-share-button").click(function() {
        $("#<%=hidTwitterSharedMonitorId.ClientID%>").val($(this).data('monitor').monitorId);
    });
});

<a href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet" class="twitter-share-button" data-monitor='{"monitorId":<%#Eval("ID")%>}' data-count="none">Tweet</a>
```